# Does polarized light come from being transmitted through something or can it be emitted?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, visible-light

In other words is polarized light ever directly emitted?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, many physical processes can produce polarized light directly.  For example, [many lasers produce polarized output](https://www.rp-photonics.com/polarization_of_laser_emission.html).  Indeed, polarization can be observed all the way down to the scale of [individual atoms in the laser](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0375960167905531).  At longer wavelengths, most radio antennas radiate polarized electromagnetic waves as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I was considering so called entangled photons where two photons correlate their polarization but the actual polarization they share is random. If polarization could be set so that every pair where the same then testing would be different I think.

Comment: @BillAlsept Yes, I'm quite sure.  The polarization can be experimentally measured.

Comment: @BillAlsept Spontaneous parametric down-conversion (the usual way of producing entangled photons) is a different process that isn't closely related to lasers, although in fact it can also produce polarized output photons if the input beam is suitably polarized.

Comment: that’s what I’m interested in. Why can’t they produce entangled photons that are always intentionally polarized in the vertical direction or all in the horizontal?

Comment: If the polarizations of the individual photons were already known, then there would be no superposition of the polarization states, and therefore no entanglement.